# How to add multiple SUMIFS in Excel VBAs Worksheet function

Tags: excel, vba, sumifs

I'm trying to create a formala that inside VBA worksheet functions that is the same or similar to the following inside of excel.

```
"=sumifs(U:U,O:O,"TEXT",Q:Q,"TEXT1")+sumifs(U:U,O:O,"TEXT",Q:Q,"TEXT2")"
```

I currently have

```
myanswer = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("U:U"), Range("O:O"), "TEXT", Range("Q:Q"), "TEXT1")
```

if I add more to it such as

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("U:U"), Range("O:O"), "TEXT", Range("Q:Q"), "TEXT1")+***Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("U:U"), Range("O:O"), "TEXT", Range("Q:Q"), "TEXT2"***)
```

It gives an error (I have highlighted between *** the part of the code that stops working. I'm sure there is a simple "and" or "or" function but my brain is frazzled right now. Please let me know if you need any clarification (also if there are any typos I had to translate the code over as it's on another computer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. I've only posted as an answer to show the formatting, including the line break (not required but makes code easier to read)

```
MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("U:U"), Range("O:O"), "TEXT", Range("Q:Q"), "TEXT1") _
    + Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("U:U"), Range("O:O"), "TEXT", Range("Q:Q"), "TEXT2")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm not sure why my code wasn't working. It just wanted me to ask the question to start work. I probably had a typo in my original code but either way. Thank you very much.